# Crashlytics iOS Build installs very slow

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

We have been using Crashlytics (Fabric) for iOS Builds distribution for so many months. But recently We are experiencing wired behavior with one app.

While we are trying to download the app, Sometimes it is downloading very slowly, it takes literally more than 1 hour to install the app.  It's been like this for few days only. Earlier there wasn't any issues with this app.

This is happening in one specific device only, for the other devices, the app is installing  without any issues.

We are installing on the same wifi network, same configuration on the devices.

Full of available memory, no background applications.

We have tried to restart the device, forgot and rejoin the wifi, still the issue occurs.

Can anyone please help us?

Comment: Hi! Todd from Fabric here. Connect your device to your machine. Then try re-installing the app and send me the Device Console Logs.To get them:1) Choose Window -> Devices from the Xcode menu2) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device3) To see the device logs, select the View Device Logs button under the Device Information section on the right hand panel4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel to show the device console, then click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file.

Comment: Also same in Android very slow download speed

Comment: got same problem, any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Very slow APK downloads on Android here. Could it be related to how much we use Beta in general? (number of apps, number of builds uploaded etc) My company has tons of apps, and many builds get uploaded every day.